# Hash Function in Python generating error

Tags: python, hash

So I am trying to get a grasp on Hash Functions and how exactly they work.  I have the following code but I keep getting an error when I try and run the code.

```
import sys 

def part_one():   

        foo = open('input_table.txt')
        for line in foo:
            id, make, model, year = line.split(",")
            print(make, model) 
            tuple_list = (make+model,)
        return tuple_list



def hash_one(num_buffers, tuple_list):
        #part_one()
    # A being the first constant prime number to multiply by
    # B being the prime number that we add to A*sum_of_chars
        tuple_list = part_one()
        A = 3
        B = 5
        count = 0 

        for item in tuple_list:
            for char in item:
        # sum_of_chars is the total of each letter in the word
                count = ord(char)
                count = count + tuple_list
        index = ((A * sum_of_chars + B)) % num_buffers
        return index    



if __name__ == '__main__':

    input_table = sys.argv[1] 
    num_buffers = int(sys.argv[2])
    chars_per_buffer = int(sys.argv[3])
    sys.argv[4] = 'make'
    sys.argv[5] = 'model'
    lst = []
    for item in range(4, len(sys.argv)):
        lst.append(sys.argv[item])
    print(lst)
    hash_one(lst)
```

What is wrong with my code that is causing the error? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you also add the `error` that you are receiving?

Comment: Please say what error you are getting it, what line, etc.

Comment: It is giving me a typeerror line 48 & line 29

Comment: There are no line numbers here.  Include the complete traceback (error report).

Answer (score 1):

### 1

You're calling `hash()` with no arguments, you have to hash something.

A hash of a number will just return the same number though, so it's not very interesting. It's for hashing things like strings.

### 2

`part_one` returns nothing, therefore when you call `tuple_list = part_one()`, it's value is set to `None`, and you can't iterate though it.

### 3

Passing in a list through an argument then overwriting it doesn't make any sense anyway. If you want to return a list then use a `return` statement.

### 4

It's odd to set argument variables in code, they're for reading things from the command line.

5

(Not an error, but...)
You can use a slice (`lst = sys.argv[4:]`) as an easier way to get a sub-section of a list.